# how to get list of all the Fixversions of particular project and component using JIRA REST API?

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api

Using Jira Rest API I need the list of Fix versions that belong to the particular Project and component so that I can pull out all of the jira's regarding that particular Fix version.I have gone through all of the Jira Documentation but I did not get the required answer. Can any of you please help me.

Comment: Jira cloud API or Jira server API? Also, Atlassian has a support site which you may want to try posting on.

Comment: Jira server API.I had searched a lot in the Atlassian documentation.I did not find out how to get all of the Fiversions.Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already answered in the Atlassian forum, I hope you could refer to the following post [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/How-to-bulk-get-the-versions-of-all-projects/qaq-p/62301)

You could use the REST API to fetch all the versions under a certain project using its `id` or its `key` like the below:

```
YOUR_JIRA_URL/rest/api/2/project/{projectIdOrKey}/versions
```

I have tried this on my instance and this provides all the `fixVersions` that were created under our project.

Hope this answers your query!

Comment: @GummadiVijayaKumar, Please try this option and let me know if it helps or not!

Comment: the solution you have given is O.K. now I need to get the fix-versions of Project as well as the component. What you have given is project -> fixversion  but i need project -> component -> fixversion.Is it possible?

Comment: IMHO No, FixVersion applies for a Project but not on a Component.